# there is a cuda runtime error(59) when i train my model with pytorch

Tags: pytorch

there is a cuda runtime error(59)  when i train my model with pytorch. [I get the error as: "assertion ‘THCNumerics::ge(val,zero)’ failed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir59a.jpg)

I get a cuda runtime error(59) when i train model, just like that picture. The problem  appeared when i use 128000 pieces of data for training, but didn't appear when i used 12800 pieces of data for training.Also, I used the DataLoader to load 128 piece of data per batch.the code that prompts for the problem is :

```
  for i in range(batch_size):
            idxs_data = idxs[i].data
            for j in range(seq_len):
                if mask[i][j] == 1:
                    pass
```

"if mask[i][j] == 1:" is the error code

Comment: Post the code that is causing this error. We can help you, if you furnish more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response.This is the first time that i use stack overflow.i can not copy my code in comments,so that i modified my question